# how to make chained model auto read the conditions?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two models called `Batch` and `User`

`Batch` has the following

```
public $belongsTo = array(

    'Customer' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'conditions' => array('Customer.group_id' => CUSTOMERS),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '', 
    ),
);
```

When I do the following:

```
$customers = $this->Batch->Customer->find('list');
```

I fully expected to get back just the users whose `group_id` matches `CUSTOMERS`. It returns ALL the records in the `users` table.

However, I actually have to write

```
$customers = $this->Batch->Customer->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Customer.group_id' => CUSTOMERS)));
```

Is there a way so that the chained model `User` knows that it is called as `Customer` by `Batch` and therefore automatically reads the correct conditions in the associations found in `Batch` model?

I want to make my code more readable hence the motivation for this question.

I want to write simply

```
$customers = $this->Batch->Customer->find('list');
```

or something similarly straightforward.

Of course, I realized that if I do the following:

```
$batches = $this->Batch->find('all');
```

The condition stated in the associations will be used. But I don't want to find batches. I want to find just customers.

I am using CakePHP 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

1)

do nothing.

Continue to use code like

```
$customers = $this->Batch->Customer->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Customer.group_id' => CUSTOMERS)));
```

2)

[create a custom find method as suggested by arilia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19289870/80353).

3)

write a `getCustomers` method inside `Batch` model

where it looks something like this:

```
public function getCustomers($type, $query = array()) { 
    if (empty($query['conditions'])) {
        $query['conditions'] = array();
    }
    $query['conditions'] = array_merge($query['conditions'], array('Customer.group_id' => CUSTOMERS));
    return $this->Customer->find($type, $query);
}
```

then you can call

```
$customers = $this->Batch->getCustomers('list');
```

**UPDATE:**

I have written a [Plugin](https://github.com/simkimsia/UtilityBehaviors) that helps with this kind of behavior, utilizing the 3rd solution.

```
 class Batch extends AppModel { 
   public $name = 'Batch'; 

   public $actsAs = array('UtilityBehaviors.GetAssoc'); 
   public $belongsTo = array(
      'Customer' => array(
           'className' => 'User',
           'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
           'conditions' => array('Customer.group_id' => 7),
           'fields' => '',
           'order' => '', 
       ),
   ); 
 }
```

You can fetch just the customer data when you are in BatchesController this way:

```
 $customers = $this->Batch->getAssoc('Customer', 'list');
 $customers = $this->Batch->getAssoc('Customer', 'all');
 $customerCount = $this->Batch->getAssoc('Customer', 'count');
```

This behavior has tests at [travis](https://travis-ci.org/simkimsia/UtilityBehaviors) and you can read about the tests written at [github](https://github.com/simkimsia/UtilityBehaviors/blob/master/Test/Case/Model/Behavior/GetAssocBehaviorTest.php#L149).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't

but you can create custom find types in `User` model file

```
public $findMethods = array('customer' =>  true); //this enable a custom find method named 'customer'

protected function _findCustomer($state, $query, $results = array()) {
        if ($state === 'before') {
            $query['conditions'] = array('group_id' => CUSTOMERS);
        }
        return parent::_findList($state, $query, $results);
    }
```

and in `BatchesController`

```
$this->Batch->Customer->find('customer');
```